# Como editar formato de resultados en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Existe alguna forma de dar formato especifico a un procedimiento almacenado en SQL?
tengo un procedimiento que me devuelve la cantidad total de:empleados, clientes, categorias y proveedores registrados en mi sistema.

Existe alguna forma de que si la cantidad es menor de 10 agregarle un "0" delante? osea, en vez de :

total de cliente: "1", sea "01"

este es mi procedimiento

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[DashboardMANTENIMIENTOS]
@NCATEGORIAS INT OUT,
@NCLIENTES INT OUT,
@NPROVEEDORES INT OUT,
@NEMPLEADOS INT OUT
as
begin

SET @NCATEGORIAS= (select count (ID) as CantidadCategorias from Tab_categorias)
SET @NCLIENTES=( select count (ID) as CantidadClientes from Tab_clientes)
SET @NPROVEEDORES= (select count (ID) as CantidadProveedores from Tab_proveedores)
SET @NEMPLEADOS= (select count (ID) as CantidadEmpleados from Tab_empleados)

end
```

Gracias de antemano,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `RIGHT` para hacer un relleno por la izquierda.

```
     select 
       RIGHT('00' + cast(count (ID) as varchar),2)  as CantidadClientes 
     from Tab_clientes
```

[Referencia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hola @Lobos, haciendo una consulta normal, osea solo tu respuesta como query, funciona perfectamente, pero si la uso dentro de mi procedimiento, no funciona.

Comment: Olvidalo, ya encontre porque no funciona, es porque estamos agregando un numero "0" a la izquierda de un numero entero, es decir, internamente lo realiza, pero visualmente no lo muestra. La solucion es, los parametros que tengo como INT convertirlos a varchar.